# Is "closedness" a proper word?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, relations

In one of my papers I had to prove a list of properties of a set, say, $S=\{a,b,c\}$. Among them we have a fact that $S$ is downward closed with respect to a binary relation $R$. I found it awkward to start proving the property by saying "Regarding downward closedness, the set $\{a,b,c\}$ is downward closed, since ... ."
Is using the word "closedness" a good style or is there a better replacement? How would you reformulate the sentence?

Comment: "To show that the set $\{ a,b,c\}$ is downward closed, ..." seems nicer to me.

Comment: IME, "closedness" usually seems to come up when "closed" is part of a well-recognized phrase, like "downward closed" or "Cartesian closed". It doesn't sound too strange to me to also call the property "downward closure," though I can understand wanting to avoid confusion with the notion of the closure of a set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. The phrase “downward closedness” returns [plenty of Google hits from math books](https://www.google.com/search?q="downward+closedness"). But your example feels clunky, because you’re essentially introducing the proof twice. Just eliminate the “regarding downward closedness” bit and you’re good to go! Some more alternatives:

- “$S$ is downward closed: …”
- “$S$ is downward closed. To show this, …”
- “To show that $S$ is downward closed, …”